# How to connect to two PPPOE connections

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, pppoe

I'm in a network that has to connect with a PPPOE connection to get internet access:

I have two enhanced adapters in my computer with different IP addresses and two username and pass to connect with .

How can I connect to two PPPOE connections at same time?

I want to increase my internet speed.

Note: I can't access the router.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a Windows Machine? More information would be helpful.

Comment: yes win 7 32 bit

Comment: Alright, what about you not being able to access the router? You want to connect with two PPPOE credentials but you can't connect to your router yet?

Comment: I'm working in a company it's not my router it belong to company

Comment: all of users have a username to connect to internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the short answer you're looking for: You can't increase your internet speed this way.

More in-depth: You can certainly connect two devices through your ethernet adapters, however, you won't be able to access the internet on both at the same time. What I mean is, while two modems may be plugged into your machine, you browser only pulls the internet from one, not two at a time.

Also, you can't just login multiple times to one modem using different user credentials. You can only use one set of credentials at a time.

Comment: Modems could handle multiple PPPoE logins easily; _every single one_ I've used (including crap-tier D-Links) had such configuration per-interface, not globally, so there could be a set of PPP(oE) or DHCP parameters for each Ethernet port, and for each ATM circuit. For example, my ISP uses separate "Internet" and "management" circuits; same ADSL link, two separate PPPoE configs (though recently moved to DHCP). ~ Though, of course, none of this will be useful if the modem doesn't support load-balancing...

Answer (score 1):

You can get a dual WAN router like the edimax br-6624, setup 2 WAN connections and balance load between them.
However, you will have to be very careful when configuring so you won't get login anomalies or other such things due to connection switching.